# Игнорирование изменения файлов в директории

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Всем привет. Использую AMPPS как альтернативу OpenServer, только на MacOS. Проблему такую же пытался искать, но не нашел. Вынужден обращаться сюда.
Есть форма, через которую отправляются какие то данные и файл. В частности, изображение с расширением jpg. Изображение уже может существовать, тогда по задумке оно должно измениться на новое.

Вот отрывок кода, как именно происходит замена (добавление) файла в директории:

```
$i = $_POST['number_product'];
if(isset($_POST['button_change'])) {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/Applications/Ampps/www/php.learn/Work/Products/Img/00".$i.".jpg");
}
```

Так же на самой странице есть блоки с информацией и изображениями. Изображения берутся из директории Img следующим образом:

```
var is_img = new Array;
var l = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < amount_products; i++) {
     l++
     is_img[i] = "<STYLE>@import(./css/style.css)</STYLE><IMG class='is_view_img' width=95% src='./Products/Img/00"+l+".jpg'>";
}
```

И вывод изображений на саму страницу:

```
<SCRIPT>
   l = 0;
   document.write("<STYLE>@import(./css/style.css)</STYLE><TABLE>");
   for (i=0; i < conventional_unit; i++) {
       document.write("<STYLE>@import(./css/style.css)</STYLE><TR><TD>"+is_img[l]+"</TD></TR>");
       l++;
   }
   document.write("<STYLE>@import(./css/style.css)</STYLE></TABLE>");
</SCRIPT>
```

Новое изображение добавляется, все отлично работает и корректно отображается до момента, пока не начинаешь изменять изображения. Загружаю, отправляю, в директории изображение меняется. А вот на странице остается старое. Учусь в государственном учреждении, показываю проблему учителю, тот разводит руками. Я в шоке, мягко говоря.
Что я пробовал:

1. Вовсе удалять директорию Img. Никаких изменений.
2. Менять местами имена некоторых изображений. На странице реакции нуль.
3. Удалять некоторые изображения. На странице реакции нуль, все изображения на месте.
4. Перезагружал, а в последствии и менял браузеры. Как вы догадались, реакции никакой.
5. Перезагружал сам ПК, программу AMPPS, перезагрузил все что можно и нельзя. Ничего не изменилось.

Возможно, для некоторых решение этой пробелемы будет очевидно, но я, как начинающий, так не считаю. Поэтому прошу не кидаться помидорами. Заранее всем спасибо за ответы)

Comment: браузер кэширует ваши изображения. ф12 - сесть - галку про кэширование зы: зачем вам там сто раз выводится styles.css ?

Comment: Да, действительно, теперь есть изменения. Спасибо большое вам человеческое)
Про style.css, стили не применялись к элементам, которые добавлены через document.write(), поэтому вот так решил проблему. А сейчас удалил эти строчки, все прекрасно применяется. Поэтому вдвойне спасибо.